# Submit a form directly to controller

Tags: angularjs

What is the simplest way to submit a form directly to a controller?

I have a form like:
`<form name="searchForm">
    <input type="text" name="query" ng-model="query">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>`

And a controller that handles routes for `#/search?query=xxxx`.

How can I make it so when the form is submitted it's equivalent to a user clicking a link with a `href="#/search?query=xxxx"`?  I would think there would be something like `ng-action="#/search"` but I haven't found anything that simple.

Comment: Maybe try using the `ng-submit` directive to a function, then changing the route.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below points to solve your problem.

1. Use ng-submit="SaveData(pass your model value here)" as attribute of form tag.
2. Create SaveData scope method in your controller JS.
3. Create URL and use window.location to redirect.